# Data race with list.List concurrent access with mutexes

Tags: go, concurrency, linked-list, mutex, goroutine

I'm getting a data race and I can't quite figure out why. Running my tests with the `-race` command I've narrowed it down to trying to access a `list.List` while reading from it, but my Mutexes don't seem to do anything.

I have a number of *list.Lists inside of an array like so:

```
type MyList struct {
    mutex sync.Mutex
    *list.List
}

type SomeObj struct {
    data string
}

var myListOfLists [10]MyList
```

I'm reading and writing from the list like so:

```
list := myListOfLists[someIndex]
list.mutex.Lock()
for e := list.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        if (...) {
            list.MoveToFront(e)
        }
}
list.mutex.Unlock()
```

and in another goroutine also trying to read and build a full list to return

```
var fullCopy []*SomeObj
list := myListOfLists[someIndex]

list.mutex.Lock()
for e := list.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fullCopy = append(fullCopy, e.Value.(SomeObj))
}
list.mutex.Unlock()
```

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple `MyList`s with pointers to the same `list.List` in them?

Comment: Is your example of `fullCopy []string` actually accurate in that it is collecting strings, or are you perhaps returning pointers?

Comment: @RayfenWindspear yes, they are actually pointers— my mistake. Updating the q

Comment: @Adrian yes, they are pointers, but the mutation is on the list not the object. updated the q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `list := myListOfLists[someIndex]` copies the array element to variable `list`. This copies the mutex, thus preventing the mutex from working. The `go vet` command reports this problem.

You can avoid the copy by using a pointer to the array element:

```
list := &myListOfLists[someIndex]
```

Another approach is to use an array of pointers to `MyList`. While you are at it, you might as well use a list value instead a list pointer in `MyList`:

```
type MyList struct {
    mutex sync.Mutex
    list.List
}

var myListOfLists [10]*MyList
for i := range myListOfLists {
   myListOfLists[i] = &MyList{}
}
```

Comment: To avoid future accidents, would it not be better to initialize as `var myListOfLists [10]*MyList`?

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: yes, is you have an embedded mutex, you should be used a pointer type (plus there's no reason here for an array instead of a slice either)

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about go vet. That did it, thank you. Are there any other go commands that I should know about? I know about test and the -race flag, and now go vet; and that's about it.